# Can I choose which OS I want to startup with while booting

Tags: boot

I have Windows 7 Professional. Will the system ask me with which OS it will start (Windows or Ubuntu) on startup or will it load only Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes**, if you installed Ubuntu *after* Windows 7, [GRUB](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/) (GRand Unified Bootloader) will keep track of all the OSes on your system and allow you to choose which you want to boot on startup.

GRUB is what is known as a Bootloader, and Windows uses a transparent one that just boots the OS. GRUB, on the other hand, displays a text-based menu to allow you to choose what OS you want to load. It normally defaults to Ubuntu, and will load the default OS after a 10 second wait period, but you can manually choose and have it boot Windows.